# deploying/running apps that have strongly named assemblies

Tags: .net

In our development environment we use 1 snk file that is used on assemblies signed with vs signing tab on a project.  We also run `sn -Vr *, someKey`.  However when I tried to run an exe that use these assemblies I get

> Exception Details: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'AjaxControlToolkit' or one of its dependencies. Strong name signature could not be verified.  The assembly may have been tampered with, or it was delay signed but not fully signed with the correct private key. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131045)

Do I have to register them all in GAC with sn utility?

By the way we also check Delay Sign Only checkbox.

Comment: You check delay sign you must complete the assemblies signature latter. Remove the check and your app will run as expected.

Comment: If I remove the check, than solution doesn't build.